# Error in pom.xml - Failure to transfer org.jacoco jacoco-maven-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a parent project with different  and now I get the following error:

> Failure to transfer
>   org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:pom:0.6.2.201302030002 from
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached   in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.   Original
>   error: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:pom:0.6.2.201302030002 from/to central
>   (http://  repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin/
>    0.6.2.201302030002/jacoco-maven-plugin-0.6.2.201302030002.pom

I tried it with 0.5.7.201204190339 AND 0.6.2.201302030002 and ${jacoco.version} . But now success :-(

I use Spring Tool Suite - Version: 3.6.0.RELEASE and I have installed m2eclipse Plugin.

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
              <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
              <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <!-- <version>${jacoco.version}</version>  -->
              <version>0.5.7.201204190339</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${jacoco.skip}</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are behind corporate firewall or other proxy then you need to create `settings.xml` file and specify credentials for proxy server like below.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>my_proxy</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>{proxy server address}</host>
            <port>{proxy server port}</port>
            <username>{user name to be used for proxy}</username>
            <password>{password to be used for proxy}</password>
            <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
</settings>
```

Other thing you may try is to delete repository directory and try again.

If you are using eclipse then you need to configure proxy settings in Eclipse too. Goto Window -> Preference -> type 'proxy' in search box.

In `Network connections`, choose 'Active Provider' as `Manual` and then set proxy settings for HTTP and HTTPS. Do not set proxy for SOCKS.

One of these solutions always work for me :)

Comment: i already have my proxies set in my settings.xml, Deleting the repository directory worked fine to me !